# When can CoroutineScope.launch throw?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a scenario where when a request is received there should be an immediate response about the request being acknowledged, yet not processed. Processing is carried out asynchronously and it may throw some exceptions.

Are these `try-catch` blocks an over exaggeration in such case?

```kotlin
fun handleRequest(request: Request): String {
  try {
    GlobalScope.launch { 
      try {
        process(request) 
      } catch (e: Exception) { 
        notifyAboutProcessingFailureAsync(request, e) // sends a response, another, separate request back to caller, with information about failure
      }
    }
    "processing"
  } catch(e: Exception) {
    notifyAboutProcessingFailureAsync(request, e)
    "failure"
  }
}
```

This seems wrong-ish also for instance that this code notifies about failure twice - once when synchronous response `"failure"` is created and second time when `notifyAboutProcessingFailureAsync` does its job.

Is there a (plausible) scenario where `CoroutineScope.launch` actually throws? So the code can be simplified to something like

```kotlin
fun handleRequest(request: Request): String {
  GlobalScope.launch {
    try {
      process(request)
    } catch (e: Exception) { 
      notifyAboutProcessingFailureAsync(request, e)
    }
  }
  "processing"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`launch` is asynchronous and never throws. Your first function as written will always return `"processing"` and never reach the outer catch block. If you also eliminated the `catch` inside the coroutine, it still wouldn't throw, since it's asynchronous.

(When a `launch` coroutine has an uncaught exception, the default behavior is to cancel its parent Job, but if the scope that launched it is using a SupervisorJob, that won't happen either.)

Your second function is more sensible. (Ignoring the antipatterns that I assume are there because this is just a quick example.)